# Why is my EC2 Auto Scaling Group growing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I noticed that the name of one of my EC2 instances (**control-panel-0**) is duplicated multiple times in the list of running instances (see screenshot).

[image: Running Instances]

I understand that this instance is part of an Auto Scaling Group and is spawning new instances, most likely due to the CPU or file system usage exceeding some threshold.

My question is: How can I tell what resource shortage triggered the duplication?  Was it CPU usage?  File system usage?  How can I tell?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot as example?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge I edited the question and added a screenshot.

Comment: Instance names need not be unique. Instance IDs are unique. Example: when you use an Auto Scaling Group and have a Name tag assigned to the ASG, all instances that are created will have the same name.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 I understand that all of these instances are part of the same ASG, what I'm asking is how can I determine what is causing so many instances to be in the ASG.  What is making the ASG grow?

Comment: Go to the ASG console and under Activity History, it will summarize why a new instance was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the **EC2** section, navigate to the **Auto Scaling Groups** area.
2. Select the Auto Scaling Group you want to investigate and select the **Activity History** tab.
3. Expand any of the "Launching new EC2 instance" activities and AWS will show you a **Description** and a **Cause**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your instances are not duplicated, their name tag is.

Instance names need not be unique. Instance IDs are unique and is what AWS uses to identify certain resources.

In this case, you are either using an autoscaling group, which creates new instances when scaling needs to happen, or somebody manually named all these instances the same.

You can see in the Auto Scaling Groups tab logs (if there is any) why new instances were added.